# laravel 4 - add to paginated collection

Tags: collections, laravel, paginator

I want to manually add items to a collection - works fine with a collection returned from get(), but fails when collection returned from paginate(), e.g.

```
$rows = $query->get();
$rows->add(new Model());
```

working fine

```
$rows = $query->paginate(10);
$rows->add(new Model());
```

give this error: Paginator.php 502: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' does not have a method 'add'

I guess paginate is returning a paginator object rather than an eloquent collection, just wondering if there is a way to append to this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel 5**:

```
$rows->getCollection()->add(new Model());
```

**Laravel 4:**

`add` is `Eloquent\Collection` method and you can't use it on the `Paginator` which relies on `Support\Collection`.

Use this workaround if you need to append items:

```
$items = $rows->getItems();
$items[] = new Model();
$rows->setItems($items);
```

Comment: How can we do this with Laravel 5?